# moduli space of two-term complexes of vector bundles over a fixed variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, homological-algebra

Let $X$ be a fixed algebraic manifold over $\mathbb{C}$ , $\{E_{a}\}$ be vector bundles over $X$. We  can construct moduli space of $\{E_{a}\}$ by classical theory. My question is that if we consider the category $\mathcal{C}$ of two-term complexes$\{E_1 \xrightarrow{\phi} E_2\}$ where $E_1,E_2$ are vector bundles over $X$ and $\phi$ is homomorphism between bundles. How to define the equivalence relation of two objects of $\mathcal{C}$ and construct moduli space of $\mathcal{C}$ (if we can) ?

I heard that there is some results on GIT construction of complexes and recent progress on derived objects. Who can tell me where I can find some  useful results (in some papers)?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paper:Moduli spaces of holomorphic triples over compact Riemann surfaces

Comment: Providing complete references (at least the authors!) is somewhat more scholarly...

Comment: arxiv.org/abs/math/0211428v2

Steven B. Bradlow , Oscar Garcia-Prada , Peter B. Gothen

Comment: You can edit your answer and add the information there.